# std::any set performance and a shortcut

Tags: c++, c++17

So, I was profiling my code and found something bad. Turns out setting value to std::any can be a bit slow. Turns out that if you keep setting something of same type, let's say int, into one it keeps resetting its memory. AFAIK it seems to delete and reserve memory EVERY time. Horrible.

Any reason for this?

I made this to test it and found it to be an upgrade to the existing version:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <any>

template<typename T>
void set_any_value(std::any & p_out, T const & p_value)
{
    p_out = p_value;
}

template<typename T>
void set_any_value_with_shortcut(std::any & p_out, T const & p_value)
{
    if(p_out.type() == typeid(T))
    {
        *(std::any_cast<T>(&p_out)) = p_value;
        return;
    }
    p_out = p_value;
}

int main()
{    

    std::any num;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int index = 0; index < 1000000; index++)
    {
        set_any_value(num, index);
    }
    
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Without shortcut " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for(int index = 0; index < 1000000; index++)
    {
        set_any_value_with_shortcut(num, index);
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "With shortcut    "<< (end - start).count();
}
```

Turns out it's quite fast in comparison.

```
Without shortcut 18720000
With shortcut    2660000 
Normal program termination. Exit status: 0
```

Can anyone see any issue with this? Maybe I overlooked some case where it won't work? -O3 still shows a massive speedup.

EDIT:

I did run it at -O0 first.

Note that in my case the type doesn't change. So if you want to test this and show that it's not actually faster, then you have to run it by setting the same type to a specific any object each time.

Comment: `std::cout << "Without shortcut " << std::chrono::nanoseconds(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() << std::endl;` -- I don't think it's a good idea to stop the timer in the middle of `operator <<`.  The `now()` should be done on a separate line immediately after the code you are timing.

Comment: I would worry about the compiler optimizing the benchmarking loops away. Other than that, the anycast looks fine to me but I would remove the `if` based on typeid and add `if` checking the `nullptr` result of the cast.

Comment: You need to throw in some other types, otherwise it may optimize away the expensive `p_out.type() == typeid(T)` test. I tried it out on quick-bench:  https://quick-bench.com/q/TgKAWoAEfJ_z5N8pa_pJzCR3zh0 - it doesn't look good for the shortcut

Comment: Have you tried std::any.emplace()? The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/emplace) is a bit confusing. May be it can reuse an existing storage with that (resetting in this case, will only destroy the existing object but not its storage). I would be interested by a bench on that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie good call, changed the code but the issue shortcut is still faster on gcc at least.

Comment: @Oersted It wouldn't change anything. It would still reallocate the storage. What's differ is that it would emplace the object inside the newly allocated space instead of copying it (but for non-class types, it's useless to use emplace).

Comment: @TedLyngmo In the use case I need this for, the type doesn't change and the any object contains the same type as is being set into it.

Comment: @Oersted Then can't the type be deduced at compiletime so that you don't have to use `std::any` at all? In any case, you could remove the type check. Only the first assignment would need to be done in the standard way

Comment: @Fareanor: got it, thanks.

Comment: @Tedlyngmo indeed...

Comment: @Oersted Sorry, I meant to tag 0xbaadf00d in my previous comment :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo no worries! ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone see any issue with this?

I think what you are seeing, because you only use one type, the compiler is optimizing away the type test and makes it into:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void set_any_value_with_shortcut(std::any & p_out, T const & p_value)
{
    *(std::any_cast<T>(&p_out)) = p_value;
}
```

... where `T` is `int`.

If you want to test the effect, you need to make sure that the type test is still left in the assembly. You could do that by sometimes assigning variable of a different type to the `std::any`.

Here's one benchmark where 999 out of 1000, it will assign an `unsigned` to the `std::any`. If the type test would actually help in those cases the types match, I would assume that this would show that the shortcut would improve performance. It however shows that the shortcut is ~1.2 times slower:
https://quick-bench.com/q/5TKa40_Kf5KMANyY5gKqK5zvpXA

Comment: quick-bench looks nice, I'll test it there. I actually saw this in callgrind, it's deleting the old content each time it was assigning a value.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d Yes, quick-bench is very nice for setting up quick benchmarks. More than once have I proven my own assumptions about my hand-optimizations wrong by using it :-)

Comment: Yeah, turns out that if you assign a value of random type then yes.. it's worse. For my use case the value isn't random, it's always the same.

Comment: Oh, but if it's always the same, then using a `std::any` doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: True, but I can be different for different objects. It's kinda complicated. It's always the same in a certain context.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d It's usually possible to solve with templates, which should improve performance since you can then skip the `any_cast`